# Rails: How to send emails to a recipient containing umlauts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, utf-8, diacritics

I'ld like to send an email with the following setup

```
def registration_confirmation(user)
  recipients    user.username + "<" + user.email + ">"
  from          "Netzwerk Muensterland<mailer@netzwerkmuensterland.de>"
  subject       "Vielen Dank für Ihre Registrierung"
  body          :user => user
  content_type  "text/html"
end
```

The subject line contains an umlaut and works fine. 
The log says me, it was encoded like this:

```
=?utf-8?Q?Vielen_Dank_f=C3=BCr_Ihre_Registrierung?=
```

But, if the user.username contains umlauts, the email will not send. I am using a google apps smtp server. How do I accomplish a encoding like this for recipients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it! There is a ActionMailer method called quote_if_necessary which takes care of this kind of problem.

```
def registration_confirmation(user)
  recipients    quote_if_necessary(user.username, "utf-8") + "<" + user.email + ">"
  from          quote_if_necessary("Netzwerk Münsterland", "utf-8") + " <mailer@netzwerkmuensterland.de>"
  subject       "Vielen Dank für Ihre Registrierung"
  body          :user => user
  content_type  "text/html"
end
```

Comment: Not required if you're on Rails 3.

`code`
If you are using UTF-8 as your character set, you do not have to do anything special, just go ahead and send in UTF-8 data to the address fields, subject, keywords, filenames or body of the email and Action Mailer will auto encode it into quoted printable for you in the case of a header field or Base64 encode any body parts that are non US-ASCII.
`code`