# How can I make my mailer deliver a message to an address containing umlauts under Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

This is my mailer:

```
class MyUserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "me@mail.com",
          :content_transfer_encoding => "7bit"
  def build_email(user)
    mail(:to => user.email,:subject => "Welcome")
  end
end
```

I'm testing with an address containing umlauts: `äardvark@mail.com`, but I keep receiving the following error, when I try to deliver the email:

```
'to' parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation
```

Documentation says that the mailer will use UTF-8 to encode all the fields. How can I make this work?

EDIT: I'm using Rails 3.2.5

Comment: Possible duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961281/rails-how-to-send-emails-to-a-recipient-containing-umlauts

Comment: You do realize that the question you're linking to refers to Rails 2?

Comment: The problem seems to be related to `mailgun-rails`, and not to ActionMailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by my usage of the mailgun Rails gem. After I switched to using smtp directly, problem went away.